# Adding cell value to dictionary based on other cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I have to add values of column(Number) to Dictionary based on column(Status).
If column(Status) has E,then add to dictionary_1
Else then add to dictionary_2.

[image]

I am facing the problem if column(Number) has both "E" and blank it gets added to both the dictionary. what can be done in below to rectify this problem?

```
Set DATA = wkb.Worksheets("download")
DATA.Activate  

currentReadRow_status = START_ROW_DOWNLOAD

currentReadVariable = Trim(CStr(DATA.Cells(currentReadRow, COL_DOWNLOAD_NUMBER)))


download_status = Trim(CStr(DATA.Cells(currentReadRow_status, COL_DOWNLOAD_STATUS)))

  While (currentReadVariable <> "")
  If (download_status = "E") Then
     If Not (DOWNLOAD_ERROR.Exists(currentReadVariable)) Then
     DOWNLOAD_ERROR.Add currentReadVariable, download_status
     End If
  Else
    If Not (DOWNLOAD_NOERROR.Exists(currentReadVariable)) Then
    DOWNLOAD_NOERROR.Add currentReadVariable, download_status
    End If
 End If
    currentReadRow_status = currentReadRow_status + 1
    currentReadVariable = Trim(CStr(DATA.Cells(currentReadRow_status, COL_DOWNLOAD_NUMBER)))
    download_status = Trim(CStr(DATA.Cells(currentReadRow_status, COL_DOWNLOAD_STATUS)))
Wend
```

Comment: Questions with no code shared tend to get quickly closed...

Comment: Added the code for the problem

Comment: @Vasily Could you explain a little further as I am new to VBA?

Comment: how would you like to treat a _Number_ should it be associated with both an "E" and a blank cell? Should the first occurrence win? Or is "E" _stronger_ than blank?

Comment: @user3598756 If E exists for Number(irrespective other entries for that Number are blank) then it should be in error_dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you have issue with the logic, both dicts contain same value because when you insert the value into `noerror` you've not checked that you already insert this value into `error` dictionary and vise versa, so your modified code is below, I guess it would solve the issue:

```
While (currentReadVariable <> "")

If (download_status = "E" And _
    Not DOWNLOAD_ERROR.Exists(currentReadVariable) And _
        Not DOWNLOAD_NOERROR.Exists(currentReadVariable)) Then

        DOWNLOAD_ERROR.Add currentReadVariable, download_status

ElseIf (Not DOWNLOAD_NOERROR.Exists(currentReadVariable) And _
            Not DOWNLOAD_ERROR.Exists(currentReadVariable)) Then

        DOWNLOAD_NOERROR.Add currentReadVariable, download_status
End If

currentReadRow_status = currentReadRow_status + 1
currentReadVariable = Trim(CStr(Data.Cells(currentReadRow_status, COL_DOWNLOAD_NUMBER)))
download_status = Trim(CStr(Data.Cells(currentReadRow_status, COL_DOWNLOAD_STATUS)))

Wend
```

also, as I've previosly mentioned in comments below your post, can be some problems with comparing, when you compare some text with number for instance, maybe it's not your current case, but you should take into account  "case sensitivity" and variable types for such tasks. To remove case sensitivity you can use standard approach like below:

```
Sub yourSub()
Dim Dic as Object: Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dic.CompareMode = vbTextCompare '<~~~~~ remove case sensitivity for dictionary
'''code'''
End Sub
```

or using another way:

```
Option Compare Text '<~~~~~ remove case sensitivity for module
Sub yourSub()
Dim Dic as Object: Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
'''code'''
End Sub
```

also, be carefull with `trim`, sometimes better to use `worksheetfunction.trim` instead of `trim`, the code below will shows you difference:

```
Sub testTrim()
Dim sTrim$, sWFTrim$, stringcheck$

stringcheck = "1    1   1    11111111"

sTrim = Trim(stringcheck)
sWFTrim = WorksheetFunction.Trim(stringcheck)

MsgBox "This is how `Trim` works: [" & sTrim & _
        "], LEN is: " & Len(sTrim) & vbNewLine & _
        "This is how `worksheetfunction.trim` works:[" & _
        sWFTrim & "], LEN is: " & Len(sWFTrim)

End Sub
```

[image]

I hope it will help.

Comment: it seems to me your code doesn't account for OP's specification that _"If E exists for Number (irrespective other entries for that Number are blank) then it should be in error_dictionary"_, since if a given _number_ is first encountered as _not-"E"_ it gets added to `DOWNLOAD_NOERROR` dictionary, and there it only stays

Answer (score 0):

you could first process data with "E" and fill `DOWNLOAD_ERROR` dictionary and then process other data with a preliminary check the *number* isn't already in the `DOWNLOAD_ERROR` dictionary.

as follows:

```
Dim cell As Range

With wkb.Worksheets("download") '<--| refer wanted worksheet in wanted workbook
    With .Range(.Cells(2, COL_DOWNLOAD_STATUS), .Cells(.Rows.Count, COL_DOWNLOAD_NUMBER).End(xlUp)).Columns(1) '<--| consider its columns A from row 1 down to last non empty row
        For Each cell In .SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants) '<--| loop through non blank ("E") cells only and fill DOWNLOAD_ERROR dictionary
            currentReadVariable = Trim(CStr(cell.Offset(, COL_DOWNLOAD_NUMBER - COL_DOWNLOAD_STATUS)))
            If Not (DOWNLOAD_ERROR.Exists(currentReadVariable)) Then DOWNLOAD_ERROR.Add currentReadVariable, download_status
        Next cell

        MsgBox .SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeBlanks).Address
        For Each cell In .SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeBlanks) '<--| loop through blank cells only and fill DOWNLOAD_ERROR dictionary after preliminary checking
            currentReadVariable = Trim(CStr(cell.Offset(, COL_DOWNLOAD_NUMBER - COL_DOWNLOAD_STATUS)))
            If Not (DOWNLOAD_ERROR.Exists(currentReadVariable)) Then If Not (DOWNLOAD_NOERROR.Exists(currentReadVariable)) Then DOWNLOAD_NOERROR.Add currentReadVariable, download_status
        Next cell

    End With
End With
```